# SSRS reports - functionality reuse

Tags: oop, reporting-services, xsd, business-intelligence

Every month there is a bunch of new reports delivered to customer.
And I am really starting to be pissed up and I am thinking about buying long whip on developers. The first problem is: I am quite newbie in SSRS, BIDS. I have OOP paradigm experience.
The second problem is: There is some functionality, that is always the same in every report. Like calculating YTD, YTD for current period (you are right, it is wrong we do not have this in OLAP, but with present state of project it is more realistic to win jackpot than do this change), exporting reports etc. And every second report has this wrong.

So, with my optimistic view, there could be some approach to solve it in the OOP like aproach. Like do some report from which all reports will inherite or something like this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pissed up?  Stop drinking on the job.  Problems are easier :)

Comment: What Reporting Services version does this apply to?

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor It was half joke.

Comment: Sounds like you may need better developers instead of a whip. Or you need a better work environment with more realistic deadlines.

Comment: @Bob Horn I think you may need to work on the way to pick up important things from text. PS: I do not know where are you from, but in our country we do not use whips. That unimportant part of the text with whipping was more than exaggerated. But I understand you can be concerned by it, for example if you are from some country where physical abuse on workspace is acceptable

Comment: I meant whip in the same way that you did; not literally. I find it interesting that we could both use that term, yet you find fault with my use of it.

Comment: @BobHorn i need neither better developers nor persecute developers. The meaning of whip was rather expression of short lived anger without any special meaning. I still think you misunderstood. But, this in not unusual through written expression. Everybody of us has probably another cultural background, so everybody of us can see the words in another connotation.

Comment: I recommend pissing down, rather than up.  Avoids hitting yourself in the face.

Answer (score 0):

Either use [Shared Datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636147.aspx) or create [views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in your database to base the reports off.

Comment: We use both. The problem is our architecture is extremely fragile from historical reasons. We have around 300 reports and need to unify it. If we do some changes to datasets or views, suddenly half of reports can stop working (lot of mdx, in every report it is unique code). It seems hopeless, nobody will to pay for structural changes.